# Is there an interface that can be used as a parameter in a method for T[] (an array of type T) and for List<T>

Tags: c#, arrays, list, interface, polymorphism

I have two methods that perform the same task: one receiving an array parameter and the a List parameter, both of type string.
Is there a way to replace these two methods by a single method? What type of parameter can replace both?
The methods are:

```
    public static void NumberLinesInCollection(List<string> list, int startNumberingFromRowNumber = 0)
    {
        int numberOfLines = list.Count;
        for (int i = startNumberingFromRowNumber; i < numberOfLines; i++)
        {
            string sourceString = (i + 1).ToString();
            string resultingString = StringOperations.PadWithBlanks(originalString: (i + 1).ToString(), 
                                                                    fieldLength: numberOfLines.ToString().Length, 
                                                                    position: PaddingDirection.left);
            list[i] = resultingString + ". " + list[i];
        }
    }
```

and

```
    public static void NumberLinesInCollection(string[] arrayOfStrings, int startNumberingFromRowNumber = 0)
    {
        int numberOfLines = arrayOfStrings.Length;
        for (int i = startNumberingFromRowNumber; i < numberOfLines; i++)
        {
            string resultingString = StringOperations.PadWithBlanks(originalString: (i + 1).ToString(),
                                                                    fieldLength: numberOfLines.ToString().Length,
                                                                    position: PaddingDirection.left);
            arrayOfStrings[i] = resultingString + ". " + arrayOfStrings[i];
        }
    }
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: [`IList<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ilist-1?view=net-7.0)

Comment: `T[]` and `List<T>` both implement `IList<T>` (and, incidentally, `ICollection<T>` and `IEnumerable<T>`)

Answer (score 4):

From [the documentation of System.Array](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array?view=net-7.0):

> Single-dimensional arrays implement the `IList<T>`, `ICollection<T>`, `IEnumerable<T>`, `IReadOnlyList<T>` and `IReadOnlyCollection<T>` generic interfaces. The implementations are provided to arrays at run time, and as a result, the generic interfaces do not appear in the declaration syntax for the Array class.

From [the documentation of `List<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=net-7.0):

> Implements `ICollection<T>`, `IEnumerable<T>`, `IList<T>`, `IReadOnlyCollection<T>`, `IReadOnlyList<T>`, *[and a few non-generic interfaces]*

As we can see, there is a nice overlap, allowing you to choose the most fitting interface based on the actual array/list features you require.

In your particular case, `IList<T>` seems to be most suitable, since it provides both of the following features used in your code:

- an [`Item[]` indexer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ilist-1.item?view=net-7.0) and
- a `Count` property (inherited from `ICollection<T>`).

Answer (score 1):

you can use `IList<string>`, this will allow you to pass both List and Array as the parameter while calling the `NumberLinesInCollection`. array and list both implement `IList`

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay I typed wrong initially, I was typing `IList`. apology

Comment: I would add something about `IList<T>` also exposing a settable indexer, which is why it is required as opposed to the more generic `ICollection<T>`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `IEnumerable`, then it can be either `list` and `array`:

```
public static void NumberLinesInCollection(IEnumerable<string> list, int startNumberingFromRowNumber = 0)
{
}
```